# jQuery forms server-side validation messages not displayed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the current version of ASP.net MVC to display a form. Validation is taken care by the included jQuery Validate. The client-side validation is working, however, *the server-side validation is not*. Instead, form values are sent back to the server for validation, but the server's answer is being ignored by the JS validation code.

The (simplified) form looks like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Invite", "Admin"))
{        
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <ul class="griditem-list">
        <li>
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserEmail)</div>
            <div class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserEmail)</div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserEmail)
        </li>
    </ul>       
    <div class="actions">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Add" />
    </div>
}
```

The client-side javascript correctly checks for invalid email addresses and sends the email adress back to the server for further validation. The server answer gets posted back correctly (here: "This email address is already taken"):

[image]

The value is not displayed in any way, however, neither near the editor-field nor somewhere else. What could be the reason for this?

**Edit**:

This is the model that I'm using:

```
public class InvitationUser
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} darf nicht leer sein.")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "Die Emailadresse ist ungültig")]
    [Remote("EmployeeExists", "Admin", ErrorMessage = "Der angegebene User wurde bereits eingeladen.")]
    [Display(Name="E-Mail")]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} darf nicht leer sein.")]
    [Display(Name = "Vorname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} darf nicht leer sein.")]
    [Display(Name = "Nachname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<AdminUserRight> Rights { get; set; }
}
```

Here is `EmployeeExists`, which posts back the correct result of "Email address already exists":

```
    public JsonResult EmployeeExists(string UserEmail)
    {
        Guid companyId = AzManPrincipal.Current.Employee.BrokerCompany.ID;

        var container = new ModelContainer();
        if (container.BrokerEmployeeSet.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Email == UserEmail && m.BrokerCompany.ID == companyId) == null &&
            container.BrokerInvitationSet.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Email == UserEmail) == null)
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        string errorMessage = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} ist bereits registriert.", UserEmail);
        return Json(errorMessage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is the `Index` controller which renders the form:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        InvitationUser newUser = AdminUserService.CreateInvitationUser();
        return View(newUser);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating Jquery to 1.6.1 and Jquery.validation to 1.8.1 worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

If your using the following attribute:

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
```

this does not actually validate an email address. There is an email address validator in MVC 3 Futures. If you want to just implement a new type you can look at the following forum [post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1639798.aspx/1) to see how its done.

Comment: The email address gets correctly validated as an email address, but the server side validation (which checks if the email address is already taken) is not displayed.

Comment: Can you update you question with your model/controller and any attributes that it uses.

Comment: Done. Is there anything else you might need?